# mysql_connect not talking to the right host

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following issue. We moved the mysql-server to a different machine and so the ip changed but somehow the scripts on the syslog machine won't talk to the new server. 
I stripped it down to the following code to simulate the problem

my script

```php
$link = mysql_connect("mysql.domain.tld", "<user>", "<pass>");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
```

when i then execute my script it returns

```
me@syslog:~# php test.php
Could not connect: Access denied for user '<user>'@'10.254.237.42' (using password: YES)
```

But when i do a ping

```
me@syslog:~# ping -c 1 mysql.domain.tld
PING mysql.domain.tld (10.254.235.31) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

it resolves to a totally different ip (but correct ip)

So i'm currently in "wait-WHUT!!!" mode as i can't find out why it's connecting to the wrong machine. So my question is there a way to let mysql_connect always connect to a fixed ip/host in a php.ini or something?

Comment: So, why don't you use the IP instead of the alias? Moving a server to a different host, takes time to every provider to allocate the new DNS. It needs DNS flush at all.

Comment: Access denied for user, The issue is with the permissions.

Comment: @Royal Bg simple dns names don't change, and a ip can change (but in this case it will give the same result)

Comment: @Harpreet I don't think it's the permissions so much as it's contacting the wrong server..

Comment: It might not be with the permissions, since on the old host, there might not be the same users, when it's moved from there

Comment: if it's a permission problem it would say <user>@10.254.235.31 (new) instead of x.x.x.42 (old)

Comment: i'm wrong it was a privilege problemen :)

Comment: If it was a privilege problem, what were the two different IP addresses all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user you are trying to login as does not have permissions to connect from that host, in this case `10.254.237.42`. You need to add that as a valid host for the user `<user>`.

Modify this and execute on the mySQL machine:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  ‘USERNAME’@‘IP’  IDENTIFIED  BY  ‘PASSWORD’;
```

That is, you might not want to give the user ALL priviliges. Restrict it to SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc. on a specific database...

It might be that you can omit the `IDENTIFIED BY` part.

When you've done this command you need to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` when logged in.

Comment: someone didn't set the privileges correct (i swear it wasn't me :) ) solved it with this

Comment: It's always someone else :D

Answer (score 1):

If you see this error the most common reason is that you have privileges assigned for `<user>@localhost` which isn't true any more and you have to grant the same privileges to `<user>@10.254.237.42`.